# Error upgrading Google Chrome Cask using HomeBrew

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I installed google-chrome cask using HomeBrew. I'm trying to upgrade the cask but getting an error message. Here is the command sequence:

```
==> Upgrading google-chrome
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/universal/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/rkudryashov/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/88881e66883c4776fff9b3019b48a26795020439a33ddbedd3bd4620283aecd2--googlechrome.dmg
Warning: No checksum defined for cask 'google-chrome', skipping verification.
==> Purging files for version 110.0.5481.177 of Cask google-chrome
Error: google-chrome: It seems there is already an App at '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-chrome/109.0.5414.87/Google Chrome.app'.
```

I attempted to uninstall google-chrome, but get the same error message:

```
brew uninstall google-chrome
==> Uninstalling Cask google-chrome
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-chrome/109.0.5414.87/Google Chrome.app'.
```

Answer (score 1):

i have the same situation. to solve it i removed it manually and then i install it.

```
macmini$ brew install --cask google-chrome
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/universal/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/sunevil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/88881e66883c4776fff9b3019b48a26795020439a33ddbedd3bd4620283aecd2--googlechrome.dmg
Warning: No checksum defined for cask 'google-chrome', skipping verification.
==> Installing Cask google-chrome
==> Purging files for version 113.0.5672.92 of Cask google-chrome
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'.

macmini$ sudo rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
Password:

macmini$ brew install --cask google-chrome
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/universal/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/sunevil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/88881e66883c4776fff9b3019b48a26795020439a33ddbedd3bd4620283aecd2--googlechrome.dmg
Warning: No checksum defined for cask 'google-chrome', skipping verification.
==> Installing Cask google-chrome
==> Moving App 'Google Chrome.app' to '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
  google-chrome was successfully installed!
```